# There was a problem importing one of the Python modules required to run yum

Tags: fedora, yum

I installed the Python bindings of VTK 5.1 correctly. In Python, `import vtk` worked, but `import itk` did not work yet. So I wanted to install the Python bindings of ITK 4.2.

I needed to install SWIG 2.0.7, and from the error message which arose during `./configure` in the SWIG source directory, I understood I needed to install `pcre`. So I chose the version 8.31 of pcre. Here is a summary of the process:

> (VTK + Python) ---> This works.
>
> (ITK + Python) ---> SWIG needed ---> pcre needed

**Now that pcre is installed, my problem is yum has stopped working:**

```
[root@wok build]# yum
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libvtkIOPythonD.so.5.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

---

**I wonder if I should add variables to the PATH.**

Maybe it is related to a problem I had with SWIG: it worked as a user but not as root.

```
wok ~ $ swig -swiglib
/usr/local/share/swig/2.0.7

[root@wok home]# swig -swiglib
swig: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had to add one line to .bashrc of the root user to make swig work with both the user and the root:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/
```

---

**There could be something with the Python path.**

In Python, I noticed I could `import vtk` as a user, but not as root.

```
wok ~ $ python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
>>>
```

but:

```
[root@wok ~]# python
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) 
[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/user/wok/home/Softwares/VTK_5.1/build/Wrapping/Python/vtk/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from vtkCommonPython import *
ImportError: libvtkCommonPythonD.so.5.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

PCRE seems to me to be installed correctly:

```
[root@wok build]# pcretest -C
PCRE version 8.31 2012-07-06
Compiled with
  8-bit support only
  No UTF-8 support
  No Unicode properties support
  No just-in-time compiler support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

and

```
[root@wok build]# locate libpcre
/lib64/libpcre.so.0
/lib64/libpcre.so.0.0.1
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0
/usr/lib64/libpcreposix.so.0.0.0
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821144/

Comment: I solved the problem with swig, not yum though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the PYTHONPATH. It could be solved by removing one line from `.bashrc` out of four I had [copied from a tutorial](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/PythonEnvironmentSetup):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/Softwares/VTK_5.1/build/Wrapping/Python/vtk/
```

I kept the three following lines:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/Softwares/VTK_5.1/build/Wrapping/Python/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/Softwares/VTK_5.1/build/bin/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/Softwares/VTK_5.1/build/bin/
```

Now, I can `import vtk` as a user, and still use `yum` as root. 
I cannot `import vtk` as root, but I never wanted to anyway.

In order to solve the problem, I first removed the `.bashrc` file and noticed it fixed `yum`. Then I proceeded to add the lines above to the `PYTHONPATH` to gain access to `import vtk`. Finally, I noticed `ipython` would not work when `import vtk` would work, and reciprocally.